# Add counter based on groups

Tags: r, dplyr, counting

I am trying to add counter columns (`n_team` and `n_bird`) to a dataframe and am not having any success with `dplyr::row_number` and the like. Below is a reprex with the input dataframe (`df`) and the desired output dataframe (`df_counts`), as well as code for several incorrect outputs.

Thank you for your help!

```r
library(dplyr)

# Input
df <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~team,     ~bird,
    1,  "blue",  "parrot",
    2, "green",     "owl",
    3,  "blue",  "toucan",
    3,  "blue",   "finch",
    4, "green", "penguin",
    4,  "blue", "sparrow"
  )

# Desired output
# n_team is the team number within an id
# n_bird is the bird number within a team within an id
df_counts <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~team,     ~bird, ~n_team, ~n_bird,
    1,  "blue",  "parrot",      1,        1,
    2, "green",     "owl",      1,        1,
    3,  "blue",  "toucan",      1,        1,
    3,  "blue",   "finch",      1,        2,
    4, "green", "penguin",      1,        1,
    4,  "blue", "sparrow",      2,        1
  )

# Incorrect
df %>% 
  add_count(id, team, name = "n_team")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id team  bird    n_team
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       2
#> 4     3 blue  finch        2
#> 5     4 green penguin      1
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      1

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n_team =  row_number(team))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>      id team  bird    n_team
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       1
#> 4     3 blue  finch        2
#> 5     4 green penguin      2
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      1

df %>% 
  group_by(id, team) %>% 
  mutate(n_team =  1:n())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, team [5]
#>      id team  bird    n_team
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       1
#> 4     3 blue  finch        2
#> 5     4 green penguin      1
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      1

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n_team =  n_distinct(team))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>      id team  bird    n_team
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       1
#> 4     3 blue  finch        1
#> 5     4 green penguin      2
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      2

df %>% 
  add_count(team)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id team  bird        n
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot      4
#> 2     2 green owl         2
#> 3     3 blue  toucan      4
#> 4     3 blue  finch       4
#> 5     4 green penguin     2
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow     4

# Counts alphabetically
df %>% 
  group_by(id, team) %>% 
  mutate(n_bird =  row_number(bird))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, team [5]
#>      id team  bird    n_bird
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       2
#> 4     3 blue  finch        1
#> 5     4 green penguin      1
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      1

# Counts in order
df %>% 
  group_by(id, team) %>% 
  mutate(n_bird =  row_number())
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, team [5]
#>      id team  bird    n_bird
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1     1 blue  parrot       1
#> 2     2 green owl          1
#> 3     3 blue  toucan       1
#> 4     3 blue  finch        2
#> 5     4 green penguin      1
#> 6     4 blue  sparrow      1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here are some resources I consulted:

- [add counter column by arranging two variables (dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045180/add-counter-column-by-arranging-two-variables-dplyr)
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-add-a-counter-to-each-group-in-dplyr/12986/2
- https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html
- https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n_distinct.html

Answer (score 4):

Here are 4 very similar but different approaches :

1. `match` + `unique` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n_teams = match(team, unique(team))) %>%
  group_by(team, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(n_bird =  match(bird, unique(bird)))

#    id team  bird    n_teams n_bird
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <int>  <int>
#1     1 blue  parrot        1      1
#2     2 green owl           1      1
#3     3 blue  toucan        1      1
#4     3 blue  finch         1      2
#5     4 green penguin       1      1
#6     4 blue  sparrow       2      1
```

2. `factor` + `as.integer` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n_teams = as.integer(factor(team))) %>%
  group_by(team, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(n_bird =  as.integer(factor(bird)))
```

3. `data.table::rleid`

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n_teams = data.table::rleid(team)) %>%
  group_by(team, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(n_bird =  data.table::rleid(bird))
```

4. `dense_rank` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n_teams = dense_rank(team)) %>%
  group_by(team, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(n_bird =  dense_rank(bird))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible approach:

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(n_teams = cumsum(!duplicated(team))) %>%
    group_by(id, team) %>%
    mutate(n_bird = cumsum(!duplicated(bird))) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` version of this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, n_team := match(team, unique(team)), id]
df[, n_bird := 1:.N, .(id, team)]
df

#>    id  team    bird n_team n_bird
#> 1:  1  blue  parrot      1      1
#> 2:  2 green     owl      1      1
#> 3:  3  blue  toucan      1      1
#> 4:  3  blue   finch      1      2
#> 5:  4 green penguin      1      1
#> 6:  4  blue sparrow      2      1
```